# Question about the unit of measurement in the abalone data set

Tags: dataset

I downloaded the [abalone data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/abalone).
According to the website the length measurements are in mm, but I do not see how this can be. The range of values are from 0.075 to 0.815, but sea snails (blacklib abalone, haliotis rubra) are much larger than this. I also downloaded the [original report](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287546509_7he_Population_Biology_of_Abalone_Haliotis_species_in_Tasmania_I_Blacklip_Abalone_H_rubra_from_the_North_Coast_and_Islands_of_Bass_Strait), in this publication the charts suggest length between 0 and 160 mm.

I would appreciate any clarification on what the numbers in the data set mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation also says

> and the ranges of the continuous values have been scaled for use with
> an ANN (by dividing by 200).

To get the original measurements in mm,  multiply by 200.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I missed this part of the documentation (although I tried to read it carefully). Can you please tell me what ANN stands for? It is not really important (I can multiply by 200), I am just curious. From this comment you can see that I am not a machine learning expert. I am a high school teacher who is trying to add an example when teaching statistics, where the data is not made up.

Comment: ANN = Artificial Neural Network